# how to solve nerdtree.vim directory node garbled

Tags: vim, nerdtree

i use nerdtree.vim for vim, but the directory node three truns garbled.

how to config the vim to solve this problem?

screen shot:

[image: nerdtree directory picture]

Comment: i reconfig my .vimrc:let NERDTreeDirArrows=0, and solve this question:)

Comment: Post your solution as an answer if you feel it's sufficient, and mark it as accepted after the two days limit. That being said, it's probably an encoding or font error. I'd try another font/terminal and see if that solved it instead.

Answer (score 1):

`set encoding=utf-8` worked for me.

Alternative you can configure `let NERDTreeDirArrows=0`